# Adding Active Directory Users to groups progmatically issue with access

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

```
   Using pc As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CompanyDomain")
        Dim group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "FieldWorkerGroup")
        group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "FirstName.LastName")
        group.Save()
    End Using
```

Using the above code all goes fine until I try to save when I then get an UnauthorizedAccessException

I have tried adding the Authorised user to the Principal context, but still no luck.

```
Using pc As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CompanyDomain","username","password")
```

Any ideas out there as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Sys Admin, hadn't given my user that was creating the groups the correct permissions, once this was done it all worked great.